# Unique key in mongoDB nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a new collection `service`. I would like the `name` field to be unique. This is my code to create a index, then insert the document.

```
try {
        await collection.createIndex({name : 1}, { unique:true });
        return collection.insert({
            "name" : name,
            "timestamps" : {"createdAt" : dateTime, "updatedAt": dateTime},
        });
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e);
        return e;
    }
```

Upon running the code, I am getting `Error: cyclic dependency detected` error. I believe it is due to the collection not existing before the first insert. How can I ensure unique index for the `name` field.

Comment: can you give the full error stack, also why you are using mongoose?

Comment: @SAGARRAVAL It only gave me Error: cyclic dependency detected. I am using the MongoDB NodeJS Driver